# Decode encoded XHR/Ajax response payload

Tags: decryption, encodings

I'm trying to access a site using it's API with Insomnia client, but some XHR responses are encoded, it seems. I don't know the exact algorithm that's being used (but it's not base64, I tried decoding). Here's a[link](https://hastebin.com/xogagaruqa.lua) to one of the encrypted responses that I receive.

My question: can someone tell what encoding this is, or how can I proceed from here?

Comment: The decoded data has a Shannon entropy of 7.99 which means it is highly compressed or encrypted data. Thus looking at the data won't give you any details so you have to debug the code that creates or consumes this data blob.